# Not able to Unit test this class using mocking API

Tags: powermock

Its a legacy code which I am not able to unit test using Powermock. Kindly help me in unit test below class using Powermock or any other way if there is any:

**ServiceAPI class has to be unit  tested**

```
public class ServiceAPI {

    public String getServiceKey(String serviceNumber){
        String jndiUrl = getServURL();
        return jndiUrl;
    }

    public String getServURL(){
        String url = ServiceLocator.getInstance().init();
        return url;
    }

}
```

**Above class has dependency on below class which has to be mocked**

```
public class ServiceLocator {

    private static ServiceLocator serviceLocator = new ServiceLocator();

    public static ServiceLocator getInstance(){
        return serviceLocator;
    }

    public String init(){
        return "Jndi Call has return fix name";
    }   

}
```

**I have written below test**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ServiceLocator.class)
public class ServiceAPITest {

    @Test
    public void testGetServiceKey() {

        ServiceLocator serviceLocator = PowerMockito.mock(ServiceLocator.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceLocator.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ServiceLocator.getInstance()).thenReturn(serviceLocator);
        PowerMockito.when(serviceLocator.init()).thenReturn("value");
        ServiceAPI serviceAPI = new ServiceAPI();
        serviceAPI.getServiceKey("20156");
    }

}
```

**Not getting o/p. Please help!**

Comment: What issue do you have? I cannot understand. This code works fine, but doesn't test anything. You need add either assertion or verify block.

Comment: Actually it is part of a huge code where init() method has a jndi call, With that when I tried it was not returning mocked value. Also I could not understand that we are mocking ServiceLocator twice then how exactly is it working?

Comment: Base on this code snippet very hard to guess what wrong in your case, because it looks fine and works fine. I don't see any mistake here. By the way, this test framework could be interested for your: [Mockrunner](http://mockrunner.github.io/mockrunner/). It can be used for integration testing with JNDI.

Comment: Now answer on your second question. You may [here](http://www.jayway.com/2009/05/17/mocking-static-methods-in-java-system-classes/) how PowerMock works. In nutshell, you don't mocking ServiceLocator twice. Or more correctly will be say you mock it on different levels: object(instance) level and class level. In first line you create a new mocked instance of ServiceLocator, then you add interceptors to static calls for the class. After `mockStatic` the Mockito can handle static calls in same way as non-static calls.

Comment: Now I understood .. thanks for the answer, also now I am able to mock the real implementation..It was not working as few more third party jar was there and I missed to mock those dependencies...Thanks a lot!